# Replacing a GeForce 210 with a GT 1030

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, pci-express, throttling

I currently have a 2006' GT 210 graphics card in my computer and I'm thinking about buying a 2017' GT 1030 to replace it. I currently have an i3 530 and 4GB of RAM installed, and also a PCIe 2.0 slot in which my 210 runs on.

Considering that the GT 210 consumes 31W and the GT 1030 consumes 30W (1W less) and that it's made to run on a PCIe 3.0 slot, is it gonna work on my computer?

If yes, considering the other specs, am I going to have a huge loss of performance due to throttling or will it be small/not really noticeable?

Answer (score 2):

> considering the other specs, am I going to have a huge loss of performance
>   due to throttling or will it be small/not really noticeable?

There will be no notiocable throttling.

Some background:

1) A PCI-e 3 card in a PCI-e 2 slot will simply work at up to max PCI-e 2 speeds.

2) Tests done a few years ago showed that most graphics cards do not need an x16 link. Back then a mid to high end cards resulted in the following stats:

x16 card on a x16 slot: 100% of speed (by definition)
x16 card on a x8 slot: (so half the bandwidth): 2-3% performance loss
x16 card on a x4 slot: less that 10% performance drop.

Now PCIe-e v3 is up to twice as fast as PCI-e v2, so is is reasonable to place x16 3.0 to x16 2.0 in the 2-3% performance loss backet. Measurable in benchmarks, but not noticeable in regular use.

---

Caveeats:
I explicity mention mid to high level cards. Performace loss will be percentually bigger on 1000 euro top op the line dual GPU cards, and it will be less for low end cards.  And I am talking about graphics performance not OpenGL or CUDA.